# Prettier on-save different to running via npm

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, prettier

`./file.ts` (WRONG)

```js
import { jwtGroupClaimToRolesDomain, ScopeIds } from '@invison/shared';
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Response } from 'express';
import { Logger } from 'winston';
import OktaJwtVerifier = require('@okta/jwt-verifier'); // WRONG PLACE!!!!!
import { InvisonLoggerService } from '../logger/invison-logger.service';
import {
  extractBearerToken,
  generateAnonymousUser,
  generateInternalUserFromClaims,
  IInvisonJwtClaims,
  UserRequest,
} from './user-shared';
```

`./file.ts` after `npm run prettier --write ./file.ts`  (STILL WRONG)

-- no changes. i'm expecting the same results as below.

`./file.ts` after saving in VS Code (CORRECT)

```
import { jwtGroupClaimToRolesDomain, ScopeIds } from '@invison/shared';
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Response } from 'express';
import { Logger } from 'winston';
import { InvisonLoggerService } from '../logger/invison-logger.service';
import {
  extractBearerToken,
  generateAnonymousUser,
  generateInternalUserFromClaims,
  IInvisonJwtClaims,
  UserRequest,
} from './user-shared';
import OktaJwtVerifier = require('@okta/jwt-verifier'); // NOW IT'S CORRECT
```

`.prettierrc`

```json
{
  "printWidth": 120,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "useTabs": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "bracketSpacing": true
}
```

Basically, when I run prettier via VS Code and via npm I get different results. Running via npm doesn't re-order the imports. I have confirmed that ways are using the correct `.prettierrc` file.

Any ideas why this isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Prettier doesn't re-order imports. eslint will [sort imports](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/sort-imports). (and can do more advanced sorting with plugins like [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/order.md)) VSCode is running `eslint` which is sorting your import statements.

Take note of [Prettier vs. Linters](https://prettier.io/docs/en/comparison.html):

> ##### How does it compare to ESLint/TSLint/stylelint, etc.?
>
> Linters have two categories of rules:
>
> **Formatting rules**: eg: [max-len](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len), [no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs), [keyword-spacing](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/keyword-spacing), [comma-style](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-style)…
>
> Prettier alleviates the need for this whole category of rules! Prettier is going to reprint the entire program from scratch in a consistent way, so it’s not possible for the programmer to make a mistake there anymore :)
>
> **Code-quality rules**: eg [no-unused-vars](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars), [no-extra-bind](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-bind), [no-implicit-globals](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-implicit-globals), [prefer-promise-reject-errors](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-promise-reject-errors)…
>
> Prettier does nothing to help with those kind of rules. They are also the most important ones provided by linters as they are likely to catch real bugs with your code!
>
> In other words, use **Prettier for formatting** and **linters for catching bugs!**